# how does anaconda use packages installed by pip3?

Tags: pip, anaconda, python-3.6

I have been using `pip3` to install packages for python3. But I heard `anaconda` is a better choice, so I installed `anaconda`, and my `python3` is automatically connected to anaconda. Now every time I enter python3, some of my packages such as `tensorflow`, `keras` couldn't be imported.

```
>>> import tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I can find `tensorflow` and `keras` in `pip3` list, but not in conda list. I have done some google search, but my problem stays. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the output of `which python3` and `which pip3`? What platform are you on?

Comment: I am using mac, OS X El Capitan, 
which python3:
~/anaconda3/bin/python3.

which pip3:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3

Comment: Right, so your `pip3` has nothing to do with Anaconda, so it is not installing packages for Anaconda. Actually, I don't think Anaconda installs `pip3`, you just use `pip`

Comment: Isn't pip for python2? I am using python3, so I want to stick to it. Is there a way to connect pip3 to anaconda? Thanks!

Comment: pip is the shortcut to whichever version of Python it's installed for. You can check with `which pip` If it says something like `~/anaconda3/bin/pip`, it's connected to Anaconda. However, you should really prefer to use `conda` to install packages for Anaconda...